# Unable to create hard disk image

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I trying to create a hard 0.5GB hard disk and format this hard disk with the following specification

- block size -  1024 bytes
- file system type - XFS

I did run this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=VHD.img bs=1024B count=512
```

it gives me this error `dd: invalid number:  '1024B'`

If I add 1024b it creates but not 1024B

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you probably did not specify the correct block size.
From `man dd`

> N  and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes:
> c =1,w =2, b =512, kB  =1000,  K  =1024,  MB  =1000*1000,  M  =1024*1024,  xM  =M,  > GB=1000*1000*1000, G=1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

`1024b`  copies with a block size of 1024 * 512 bytes.

Your error comes from the fact that dd does not recognize `B` to be a valid number.

Comment: So, what should I run to create a disk of 0.5GB with a block size of 1024 Bytes

Comment: just `bs=1024` will do

Comment: Thanks but it did not create a block size of 1024 Bytes

Comment: The disk image file that you're creating doesn't have a "block size" - it's just a stream of bytes.  What you put for block size when using `dd` to copy files doesn't matter, it's really just a convenience (as opposed to using it with physical devices, where often a physical device *does* care what block size you use, because that's going to be the size of a single I/O request).  For the "virtual disk", it is up to whatever hypervisor you're using (I'm assuming VirtualBox) to impose a "block size" on that stream of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as designed, `1024B` is not a valid number of bytes to provide to the `dd` command.  `1024b` is valid, but it means "1024 blocks (of 512 bytes per block)", which is not what you intend - this is 512 bytes x 1024 x 512 = 128 megabytes (not 0.5 gigabytes).

The multiplier you want in this case is `M`, not `B`, and the correct command would be:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=VHD.img bs=1M count=512`

which would copy 1 megabyte x 512 = 512 megabytes, or 0.5 gigabytes.